# Definition of $L$-smooth function $f$ after scaling with a positive scalar $\alpha$, i.e., $\alpha f$

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

By definition the gradient of a function $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous if:

\begin{align}
    \tag 1 \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x- y\|.
\end{align}

For the scaled function $g:=\alpha f$, for $\alpha > 0$,
\begin{align}
\tag 2 \left\| \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) \right\| &\leq L^\prime \|x- y\| \\
    \tag 3 \left\| \left[\alpha \nabla f(x) - \alpha \nabla f(y) \right]\right\| &\leq L^\prime \|x- y\|\\
\tag 4 \left\| \alpha \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right]\right\| &\leq L^\prime \|x- y\|.
\end{align}

> Question: What is the relation between $L^\prime$ and $L$?

---

Update:

Following Arctic Char's comment, it is straight forward to show that
\begin{align}
\left\| \alpha \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right]\right\| &\leq L^\prime \|x- y\| \\
\alpha \left\| \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right]\right\| &\leq L^\prime \|x- y\| \\
\left\| \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right]\right\| &\leq \frac{L^\prime}{\alpha } \|x- y\|.
\end{align}

Thus, $L^\prime = \alpha L $.

Comment: $L = L'/\alpha$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you, makes sense. Now, I realize that it is straightforward to show this.